# Jersey 2 Swagger configuration

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, swagger

I have an issue getting swagger doc generation to work.

Here are the maven deps I used :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

I added the swagger ressources in the ResourceConfig class :

```
@ApplicationPath("REST")
public class RESTServlet extends ResourceConfig {

    public RESTServlet() {
 // ...
 // Swagger
        register(ApiListingResourceJSON.class);
        register(JerseyApiDeclarationProvider.class);
        register(JerseyResourceListingProvider.class);
// ...
   }
}
```

Then I declared a servlet to configure Swagger :

```
@WebServlet(name = "SwaggerJaxrsConfig", loadOnStartup = 2)
public class SwaggerJaxrsConfig extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("some.foo.package");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("http://localhost:8080/REST");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);

    }
}
```

With the config above, swagger servlet is picked up :if I browse to the api-docs url, I get the following :

```
{"apiVersion":"1.0.2","swaggerVersion":"1.2"}
```

However if I change the api package in the swagger servlet configuration with the real one like below :

```
@WebServlet(name = "SwaggerJaxrsConfig", loadOnStartup = 2)
public class SwaggerJaxrsConfig extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.myrealcompanypackage");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("http://localhost:8080/REST");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);

    }
}
```

I get an exception I don't understand :

```
[2015-07-23T11:05:14.802+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1437642314802] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[com.myrealcompanypackage.platform.RESTServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.myrealcompanypackage.platform.RESTServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper.iterator(Wrappers.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.to(TraversableLike.scala:629)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.to(Traversable.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:257)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toList(Traversable.scala:105)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource$$anonfun$headersToMap$2.apply(ApiListing.scala:165)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource$$anonfun$headersToMap$2.apply(ApiListing.scala:165)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.headersToMap(ApiListing.scala:165)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ApiListing.scala:87)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ApiListing.scala:86)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:206)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource$$anonfun$3.apply(ApiListing.scala:86)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource$$anonfun$3.apply(ApiListing.scala:85)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.resourceListing(ApiListing.scala:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Anyone to help ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's an old version of swagger-core. You're better off integrating the new version. Following https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5 should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apprently that would be an issue related to Jersey 4.1 Jackson libs version.

What I did in the end to make it work :

- Increased Swagger version (Thanks Ron didn't notice this new version)
- Replaced Jackson jars in `{glassfish_install}/glassfish/modules` by last version (2.6 at this time) found [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/)
- deleted osgi cache for my domain (`{glassfish_install}/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache/felix`) and restarted server.